# Will TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() work for emergency networks in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am researching an idea for a stealth detection app. If a phone which has been stolen, is switched on without a valid GSM SIM and internet access, can we gather GSM Cell details (what `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` gets) from the emergency call network (the network which allows us to call 911)? I understand that this emergency or SOS call can be routed through any cell network present at that time (which I am calling 'the emergency network'), but can we get its cell location in Android?